# C: Como gerar uma estrutura de data

Tags: c, data

boa tarde.

Estou tendo dificuldades com manipulação de datas em C.
Estou utilizando a biblioteca time.h para mexer com datas.

Preciso criar uma `struct tm` que contenha a data do dia (exemplo) 29/01/1950 e, em seguida, guardar o seu valor `time_t` em uma variável.
O problema é que crio a estrutura, atribuo os valores do dia/mês/ano para suas respectivas variáveis (`tm_mday`, `tm_mon` e `tm_year`), mas quando uso a função `mktime()`, ele me retorna -1.

Trecho do código:

```
data->tm_mday = dia;
data->tm_mon = mes - 1;
data->tm_year = ano - 1900;
segs = mktime(data);
```

Não estava tendo problemas com essa solução para datas recentes.
O que pode estar acontecendo?

**EDIT 1**: Rodando um loop pra ver até onde o mktime() funciona, percebi que ele funciona até o valor de tm_year ser igual a 70. Abaixo disso ele me devolve -1...

**EDIT 2**: Fazendo mais alguns testes, notei que o valor que o mktime() retorna é a quantidade de segundos desde 31/12/1969 22:00. Qualquer data antes disso eu não consigo criar com essa estrutura.

Answer (score 0):

O mktime() utiliza a "Era Unix", isso é uma forma de representar datas por meio de segundos. Onde uma data (juntamente com hora, minutos e segundos) é representada pela quantidade de segundos entre o dia 1 de janeiro de 1970 às 00:00:00 (UTC) e a data desejada. Portanto qualquer data anterior a isso retornará um erro.